# Residue of $\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}$ at $z=1$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I know there is a singularity of $z=1$ but I am a bit confused on how to find the residue at that point since if we have that $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ with $g(z)=1$ and $h(z)=(1-z)^3$ then $g(z)$ has a zero of order 0 (no zero) and $h(z)$ has a zero of order 3 since its first and second derivatives vanish at $z=1$ but the third derivative does not vanish at $z=1$. That is all I have, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The function $h(z)=(1-z)^3$ has a zero of order $3$ at $z=1$.

Comment: Thank you, I got confused! I'll update the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the Laurent series for $f(z)$ in powers of $z-1$?  (**Hint**: it's easy!)  What is the coefficient of $(z-1)^{-1}$ in this series?

Comment: Thank you! Does this imply that $z=1$ is an essential singularity?

Comment: Not essential at all.

Comment: What does the Laurent series look like for an essential singularity?

Comment: The definition is when an infinite number of the $b_k$'s are not zero in the Laurent expansion of $f(z)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n + \sum \limits_{n=1} b_n (z-z_0)^{-n}$ right?

Comment: So I took your hint and I came up with the Laurent Series: $\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}=\frac{b_1}{(1-z)}+\frac{b_2}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{b_3}{(1-z)^3}+ \frac{b_4}{(1-z)^4} + \dots$ which implies that $b_n=0$ if $n \neq 3$ and $b_3=1$. From this information we can see that the residue is $0$ at $z=1$ and this singularity is not essential since only a finite number of the $b_n$'s are nonzero right?

Comment: The Laurent series should have powers of $z-1$, not $1-z$, so your $b_3$ is slightly wrong.  Everything else is fine.

Comment: If I may ask, why is it powers of $z-1$ instead of powers of $1-z$? the latter are more intuitive to me

Comment: That's the definition of Laurent series, as in one of your previous comments: note the terms $(z-z_0)^{-n}$.